# Android keyboard lags/is slow while closing using adjustResize

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom layout as a form field in an activity.

The structure of the layout of the custom layout is as follows:

```
<Relative Layout A>
           <Linear Layout B>
                 <Relative Layout C>
                      <Text View>
                      <Edit Text>
                 </Relative Layout C Ends>
                 <Relative Layout D>
                      <Text View>
                      <Image View>
                 </Relative Layout D Ends>
                 <Relative Layout E>
                      <Text View>
                      <Image View>
                 </Relative Layout E Ends>
           </Linear Layout B Ends>
           <View for horizontal line>
</Relative Layout A ends>
```

This is a form field that is added into the when a button is clicked.

When the android keyboard is closed, it is slow to close and causes some lag, resulting in a momentary blank keyboard state like this:

[image: Only the edit text from the layout is visible at the moment]
    The more custom fields I add into this layout the worse this lag gets.
With 4 such fields it is a good 2 seconds.

I have tried using adjustPan instead of adjustResize in my AndroidManifest. That works but then the accessibility to the rest of my layout elements is compromised.
Does anyone have any ideas what is causing this lag, or how to solve it without compromising any behaviours? 
Thanks!

P.S.: In the picture attached, only the edit text is visible and the rest of the fields are hidden.